# Hibernate PersistentBag isEmpty() throws GenericJDBCException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity with List of entities declared as

```
@Entity
public class X {

   @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
   @JoinTable(name = ASSOCIATIONS_TO_COMPANIES_JOIN_TABLE,
              joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false) },
              inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "association_id", nullable = false) })
   private List<Association> associations = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In the service layer, I am checking the field with

```
if (entity.getAssociations() != null && !entity.getAssociations().isEmpty()) { ... }
```

which sometimes (not always, like one out of 50 calls) throws following exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:163)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)   
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:178)   
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:163)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:162)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.isEmpty(PersistentBag.java:376)
```

Does anyone know what causes it? Or at least some workaround to make it work correctly

Comment: Can you please check how the SQL statement looks like that was executed before the exception?

Comment: I unfortunately can't, this happens only on production enviroment and SQL is not logged there

Comment: And the database structure is the same and when you load data it works?

Comment: Yeah, everything is the same. I have tried to reproduce it myself but it works for me anytime, yet I get a complaint here and there randomly

Comment: I can't tell you more. Is there maybe another exception?

Comment: The collection is being lazy initialized. It's likely the connection pool has closed the connection or ran out of connections by the time this code it called (or something along thoses lines). Fix your query to retrieve the Entity and the Associations all at once. Be sure to do a left join (fetch) so that the entity gets fetched even if there are no associations.

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace. The one shown here seems to be missing the exception cause(s).

Comment: I have changed the FetchType to Eager, lets see if it helps